# How to introduce a dedicated PM and separate myself from those tasks to become a Product Manager?

Tags: product-management

Like most PMs, I wear many hats. The one which fits me better and is consuming more of my time is the Product Manager one, so I would like to start planning for the recruiting and responsibility handover of a dedicated PM so I may better focus on product management.

My vision for this person is for them to be responsible for resource allocation and chasing deliverables, preparing Gantt charts, KPI reporting, etc.

This is a currently small web development team for a large singular website, aiming to be agile.

How big does a team or my workload need to be to justify the onboarding of a dedicated Project Manager so I can focus on Product Management?

I want to avoid being a bottleneck or doing a disservice trying to juggle both roles.

Comment: If you aim to be agile you should maybe embrace a Scrum Master - Product Owner role division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every industry is a bit different. In IT, I think you will find that the cost of PM activities range from 8% to as high 15% of the total CCV.  Look at span of control, too.  I would suspect you would not have a layer of leadership unless that layer had 6 to maybe 15 direct reports.

If your team is small, looks like a part-time PM.

Comment: I think the number of direct reports makes good sense to me why I would need to continue wearing both hats for the time being. Could you please elaborate on what "CCV" means in this context?

Comment: CCV is contract cost value, or project budget.